# When returning a partial view that's AJAXed in how do I instead show an error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views

I've got some jquery that'll run ajax that runs a controller action that returns a partial view. In some cases i want to display one of several error messages (controlled by the controller), rather than replacing a DOM element with the result.

How do I achieve this?

Currently I have this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url: '<%= Url.Action("AddPostcodeToTerritory", "Territories") %>'
}).done(function(data) {
    $("#SelectedTerritoryPostcodeRows").html(data);
});
```

I have the element `SelectedTerritoryPostcodeRows` which normally gets the information, but I also want the controller to be able to give some error message which I want to display somewhere else.

Comment: Have you tried returning a JSON instead of HTML so that you can process the information and display them wherever you want?

Comment: If I returned JSON then how would I easily turn that into html (within the asp.net mvc framework)?

Comment: you could use jQuery to easily build a table for instance. Like: for(..) { var $tr = %("<tr/>").appendTo($table); $("<td/>").html("your data here").appendTo($tr); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not returning any errors, so you need some identifier in your response so your script knows what to do. Perhaps another element called errMsg, and a new if..then to handle it in this script will sort it.

```
    if (data.errMSG) {
     ..show error somewhere
    }
    else {
      $("#SelectedTerritoryPostcodeRows").html(data);
    }
```